# １から１０まで (ichi kara juu made / 一から十まで) >> What does this mean in this context?

Tags: grammar, translation, japanese-to-english, conversations, video-games

Full context: The MC is talking with a detective who pretended to accused MC as the murderer to the police — put him in jail to trick the real culprit — and then helped him escape from prison.

> D1: ボクだっていつも自分の思い通りになるわけじゃない。いや、大体目論見の半分ぐらいが成功したらいいかなって。そういうつもりで動いているんだ。最初から。
> それが君に関することは……なんていうか、**１から１０までボクの目論見通り牢屋に入って、オスカーに接触して……脱獄して……**
> もしかしてこちらの意図なんて、全部見透かされてるのかな？って思ったりしたけど、全然そんなことないし。
> 君って、底抜けのバカなの？
>
> MC: それを言われると身も蓋もないというか…

If you can please provide English translation for the sentence I don't understand

My TL "And regarding to what you did ...How should I put this, you did everything as I told from getting in jail according to my plan ,to contact with Oscar to get info... and then jail-break..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1から10まで is a set phrase that means "everything", "from beginning to end" or "from A to Z". It's synonymous with [何から何まで](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E4%BD%95%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7). We also say 1から100まで. 目論見 is "plot/plan/scheme", not "instruction".

> それが君に関することは……なんていうか、
> But when it comes to your case...how can I put this?
>
> **１から１０までボクの目論見通り**牢屋に入って、オスカーに接触して……脱獄して……
> You went to jail, contacted Oscar, and escaped, **exactly as I expected/planned from beginning to end**...
>
> もしかしてこちらの意図なんて、全部見透かされてるのかな？って思ったりしたけど、全然そんなことないし。
> (Since you're so eerily predictable) I even suspected you actually have seen through all my intentions, but it was not like that at all.

Comment: I think MC is not predictable ,he believed everything which the detective had told him (anonymously through a letter) and then proceeds to do those things when he was still in prison

Comment: @4chanuser Then "gullible" rather than "predictable". Anyway, the detective was not expecting MC would believe everything.

Comment: yeah he is like naruto lol ," I will believe in you though I don't know you or  this situation is a trap or not .And I will help you no matter what"